# How to dynamically obtain the mouse location on window and insert it on table using javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I am new to both javascript and HTML, I found a project that looks into obtaining the location of the mouse cursor within a window. So, I thought of trying to do the same but insert the values into a table. However, it seems that the values only update when I move the cursor outside the window and place it back into the test window. Is there a reason for not getting updated coordinates of the mouse cursor when I move it within the test window or did I make a mistake while coding the scripts?

```js
var win = document.getElementById("main");
win.addEventListener("mousemove", importcood);

function importcood(evnt) {
  var mouse_Posx = evnt.clientX;
  var mouse_Posy = evnt.clientY;

  var output_x = document.getElementById("loc_X");
  var output_y = document.getElementById("loc_Y");

  output_x.innerHTML = mouse_Posx.toFixed(3);
  output_y.innerHTML = mouse_Posy.toFixed(3);
}
```

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.tablecenter {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
}

.tablepadding {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="center" id="main"> Mouse Tracker Project</h1>
<div class="center"> Location of the Cursor: </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab mouseloc">
    <table id="table" border="5" class="tablecenter">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center" class="tablepadding">Mouse Location (X):
          <div id="loc_X"></div>
        </th>
        <th style="text-align: center" class="tablepadding">Mouse Location (Y):
          <div id="loc_Y"></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**Div Follower Section:**

I have been trying to get the circle to follow the mouse from the moment the mouse enters the body of the HTML, however, it only starts following when the cursor starts entering the circle. How can I change my following code to allow the circle to track the mouse?

```js
var win = document.getElementById("main");
var mse_track = document.getElementById("tracker");
win.addEventListener("mousemove", importcood);
mse_track.addEventListener("mousemove", mousetracker);

function mousetracker(evt)
{
    var cle_track = document.getElementById("tracker");
    var mouse_Posx = evt.clientX;
    var mouse_Posy = evt.clientY;
    
    cle_track.style.left = mouse_Posx  + 'px';
    cle_track.style.top = mouse_Posy  + 'px';
//    cle_track.style.visibility = 'visible';
    cle_track.style.position = 'absolute';
}

function importcood(evnt)
{
    var mouse_Posx = evnt.clientX;
    var mouse_Posy = evnt.clientY;

    var output_x = document.getElementById("loc_X");
    var output_y = document.getElementById("loc_Y");
    
    output_x.innerHTML = mouse_Posx.toFixed(3);
    output_y.innerHTML = mouse_Posy.toFixed(3);
}
```

```css
        
        .center
        {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }

        .tablecenter{
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background-color: firebrick;
            color: white;
            border-color: black;
        }
        
        .tablepadding{
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .tracker{
            position: absolute;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: blue;
            border-radius: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transition: 0s;
            /*visibility: hidden;*/
            /*pointer-events: none;*/
        }
```

```html
<html id="main">
    <head>
        <title>Mouse Tracker Project</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="center"> Mouse Tracker Project</h1>
        <div class="center"> Location of the Cursor: </div> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tab mouseloc">
                <table id="table" border="5" class="tablecenter">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center" class="tablepadding">Mouse Location (X):<div id="loc_X"></div></th>
                        <th style="text-align: center" class="tablepadding">Mouse Location (Y):<div id="loc_Y"></div></th>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="tracker" id="tracker"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks fine, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @GrafiCode well it only updates when it is only within the header title, not the whole window. did I made mistake in the HTML section?

Comment: @GrafiCode I realised that the id should be with the HTML section code not with the header code.

Comment: There's the potential that the element hasn't loaded in straight away? Could you try and wrap your listener in a DomContentLoader listener?
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  //your event listener in here
})
For example

Comment: Ok ignore that :D yeah your #main is only on your h1, good spot!

Comment: @TaylorStocks say if I wanted to create a div follower using the mouse coordinates, what parameters are needed to be able to create the function? because I have been trying to create the div but it seems that it sometimes does not follow the mouse.

Comment: @WDpad159 It seems to work great if you do it slowly - it seems if your cursor moves out of the tracker boundaries then it loses where it is. My first comment would be to move your id main onto a div which wraps the bulk of your HTML and move the tracker div outside of this. so you have 2 divs inside your body, one which has the main HTML and the tracker on its own.

Also, it also looks like you're tracking the mouse pos twice, I'd remove one of the event listeners and work from that.

Comment: @TaylorStocks Thanks for the reply and the advice, I’ll work it.